# Facebook Viewcontent Pixel Code

Tags: expresso-store, facebook

I'm trying to start implementing some dynamic marketing on Facebook. To do this, I need to use the Facebook Pixels to track users behaviors.

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
content_ids: ['1234'],
content_type: 'product'
value: 0.50,
currency: 'USD'
});
</script>
```

The issue I have is having this code update with each different product. I was able to update the code (below) using EE tags to get the data I need, but to do so, I have to place the Facebook pixel code inside the EE {exp: loop. When doing this, Facebook doesn't recognize the pixel code. If I leave it outside of the {exp: loop, the EE tags don't work.

Updated code:

```
<script>
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
        content_ids: ['{product_item_id}'],
        content_type: 'product'
        value: '{price}',
        currency: 'USD'
    });
</script>
```

Has anyone else had this issue with ExpressionEngine and Facebook Pixels? I'm running EE 2.8.1, Expresso Store 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

try adding a protect_javascript variable in in config.php:

```
$config['protect_javascript'] = 'n';
```

Comment: How will this help send the data to Facebook though?

Comment: It tells EE to ignore script tags and parse as js.